# How to calculate how weak does a magnet get when you get an other magnet closer to it?

Tags: electromagnetism

I heard that when you take two magnets and get them closer together so they reject each other (north pole to north pole or south pole to south pole) they weakens. Does anybody knows how to calculate how much it weakens depending on their distance?

And does it work the other way around? If you take two magnets the attract each other (north pole to south pole) will they get stronger? If so, how to calculate how stronger they'll get depending on their distance

Comment: It is possible to partially demagnetise a permanent magnet by exposing it to an opposing field. Definitely true of iron-based and early (AlNiCo?) alloys. For modern rare earth and ferrite magnets it is much less likely (though if you are also applying heat, it's possible). You won't find a general formula to calculate how much.: it depends on too many variables. However you may find guidelines or approximate formulas for specific materials; try the magnet manufacturers for datasheets.

Comment: A couple of examples ... http://www.asahi-kasei.co.jp/ake/en/technology/magnet/magnet.html and http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFgQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Flib.tkk.fi%2FDiss%2F2011%2Fisbn9789526040011%2Fisbn9789526040011.pdf&ei=32QrUeONM-aT0QXc2oHICg&usg=AFQjCNG-V8zS3lhxxRMhkKnzH4j-72F7ew&sig2=rug_CUXVAFln17C0ksEMFQ&bvm=bv.42768644,d.d2k&cad=rja

Comment: Brain's comment is correct.  To expand a little, you'll want to look at the 2nd quandrant of the BH curve for the magnet.  This is often called the demagnetization curve. If there is a "knee" in that curve, then it's possible you could demagnetize if the other magnet's field causes the operating point to drop below the knee.

Comment: does demagnetization means cancellinthe magnet's magnetizm? or weaken it?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I come from the world of motors where "demagnetization" generally means a weakening of the magnetic field.